# Can I do something like this in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

Started learning using CodeIgniter and I am wondering what the best way is to re-do this loop to compare two variables please...

```
<?php
    $user = array('name' => 'name', 'hasCat'=> 1, 'hasDog' => 0);
    $pets = array('hasCat', 'hasDog');
    foreach($pets as $pet) {
        echo ($pet==$user->hasCat) ? 'checked' : '';
                  the hasCat ^ is the one I want to replace to $pets??
    }
?>
```

Comment: 1) You access array elements with `[]`, means `$user["hasCat"]` and not `$user->hasCat` 2) `1` is not in `$pets`, so your ternary will always be false

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  It may be easier.

Comment: @Rizier123 thank you! can't believe I forgot... maybe I'm overthinking things.

Comment: Also, you need to use multi-arrays, since you currently have a single array with `name`, `hasCat` and `hasDog` as keys, with no internal relevance/connection. What you need is as follows = `$user = array(0 => array('name'=>$name,'hasCat'=>1,'hasDog'=>0))`

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie thank you. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the array value by doing $user->hasCat, that implies hasCat is a variable of the object $user. Try this:

```
 <?php
$user = array('name' => 'name', 'hasCat'=> true, 'hasDog' => false);
$pets = array('hasCat', 'hasDog');
foreach($pets as $pet) {
    if($user[$pet]) echo $pet;
}
?>
```